# In PowerShell, pass a complex object (SmoServer) to a background job in the ArgumentList - stuck in "NotStarted"

Tags: powershell, smo

I am trying to pass a pre-built SmoServer object to a background job, to parallelize some operations against multiple SQL Servers.  However, when I try to do this, the Child job of the invoked job gets stuck in a "NotStarted" state.  A very basic test:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
$SmoServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server MySqlServer
Start-Job -Name Test -ScriptBlock {
    param($SmoServer) 
    $SmoServer.Databases.Name 
} -InitializationScript {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO"); Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
} -ArgumentList $SmoServer
```

The job starts, but the ChildJob gets stuck "NotStarted"

```
PS C:\Users\omrsafetyo> Get-Job Test

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
5      Test            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            param($SmoServer) $Smo...


PS C:\Users\omrsafetyo> Get-Job Test | select -expand childjobs

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
6      Job6                            NotStarted    True            localhost            param($SmoServer) $Smo...
```

I had encountered this a while ago, and never found a solution.  And then I came across -IntializationScript, and thought that might be the silver bullet.  It doesn't seem it is.

This same behavior is true with Invoke-Command.  If I just run Invoke-Command, the command works fine.  However, if I run Invoke-Command -AsJob, and pass an SmoServer object, it still fails.

How do I pass these complex objects that need an assembly/module loaded up front in the ArgumentList to a background job?

Comment: I don't think you can pass objects by reference between runspaces; it's a system limitation.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I guess that would make sense.  So you think perhaps I could incorporate a RunSpace pool as outlined here: https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/ and obtain this functionality?

Comment: As it turns out, this is not a good solution.  I did get the runspaces working. However, once it was working, I ran into an issue (perhaps specific to SMO) where there were concurrency issues with the SMO object itself, in regard to read/write operations.  A better solution ended up being to use regular background jobs, and passing the instance in, and re-initializing the environment (load modules/assemblies, defining credentials,etc.) in the script block.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell jobs are run in a separate process, and objects passed as arguments are serialized (via something like `Export-CliXml` or the moral equivalent). When your object is "rehydrated" in the background process, it will not be an instance of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` anymore, but rather just an object that *looks* like one (it will have the same properties, as they were serialized in the originating process).

You *can* pass .NET objects to different runspaces within the same process. An easy way to do this would be to use the [PSThreadJob](https://github.com/PaulHigin/PSThreadJob) module.

An experiment to demonstrate what happens to objects passed to background jobs:

```
$srcFi = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new( 'C:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll' )
$srcFi.GetType().FullName
start-job -ScriptBlock { param( $fi ) $fi.GetType().FullName } -Arg @( $srcFi ) | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Output:

```
System.IO.FileInfo
System.Management.Automation.PSObject
```