# New-PSSession freezes script

Tags: powershell

I would like to create multiple Powershell sessions to my local machine to perform some operations on many files / folders at once, without slowing down my actual Powershell script. Therefore I was looking for possibilities to do multi-threading in Powershell.

The easiest approach appears to be the `New-PSSession` cmdlet. I created a test script to play around with it.

```
Write-Host "Creating session"
$NewSession = New-PSSession
Write-Host "Session created" #This line will not show up anymore...
Invoke-Command -Session $NewSession -ScriptBlock {$WSH = Create-Object -comObject WScript.Shell; $WSH.Popup("Some popup", 1) } -AsJob
```

Whenever I run it, it simply freezes when calling `New-PSSession`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why it's hanging but it's not `Create-Object`, it's `New-Object`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems `New-PSSession` hangs when not providing arguments. This is not really what `New-PSSession` is meant for anyways, you should prefer the `Start-Job` cmdlets (or you could use `Start-ThreadJob` if available to you). An example:

```
$myFirstName = "Bender"
$myLastName = "the Greatest"

$jobWithArgs = Start-Job -ArgumentList $myFirstName, $myLastName -ScriptBlock {
  Write-Output "My name is $($args[0]) $($args[1])"
}

# Do Local Script Stuff

$jobResult = Receive-Job $job -Wait

# Process the job result
```

`Receive-Job -Wait` will block until all job results have been received. Basically it'll wait for the job to finish so you don't have to write any boilerplate around that. `-ArgumentList` is optional and is used to pass in an array of arguments that can be processed within the job.

Here are additional Microsoft resources for `Start-Job` and `Receive-Job`:

- [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6)
- [Receive-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Start-Job appears to be what I'm looking for. Yet I don't quiet understand how to hand over the variables in my current scope.

Comment: I got it to work with the param-keyword now. But passing objects to my job apparently does not work?

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
param($paramWSH)
        
        $paramWSH.Popup("Text") #nothing happens
    } -ArgumentList $WSH

Neither does -InputObject:

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
param($paramWSH)
        
        $Input.Popup("Text") #nothing happens
    } -InputObject $WSH

Comment: I've updated my code sample to show how to pass in and process arguments within the job.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is just the way I did it. It works fine for primitive datatypes like string, integer, etc.., but passing a ComObject however messes up the object and it's methods won't work anymore for me.

Comment: I wouldn't pass a `ComObject` to another process, I'd pass in any required information to build it, and build it as part of that job. I think passing a `ComObject` to a thread might be safe, so you could see if `Start-ThreadJob` works for you if you don't want to rebuild the `ComObject` as part of your async job.

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541648/in-powershell-pass-a-complex-object-smoserver-to-a-background-job-in-the-argu) which explains how the object is serialized and rebuilt when passing a complex object to a background job, and why it may not work. It also states that using the `PSThreadJob` module (where `Start-ThreadJob` lives) can be used to keep the object as part of the same process. Note that threads can open up problems of their own so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to create sessions to run commands in the background; just use the `-AsJob` switch to `Invoke-Command` and collect the resulting job objects. When you want the results, pass them to `Receive-Job`.

```bsh
# Not optimal for a few reasons; this is just example code.

$jobs = @()
foreach ($block in $scriptBlocksToRun) {
  $jobs += (Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $block -AsJob)
}

# Do things that don't depend on job results here...

foreach ($job in $jobs) {
  $output = $job | Receive-Job
  # Do something with output here...
}
```

Obviously, you should consult the documentation for Invoke-Command and Receive-Job for more details.